# Fixing the Issue of Eager Loading Not Working in Blazor UI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor

I am unable to access the navigation property even though I have explicitly included it in the query using "Include". The strange thing is that the navigation property exists when accessed behind the code, but in the Blazor UI, it appears as null.

TaskTypeModel.cs

```
public class TaskTypeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public SiteModel Site { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

AddTask.razor

```
<MudSelect T="string">
  @if (taskTypes != null)
  {
    @foreach (var taskType in taskTypes)
    {
      <MudSelectItem Value="taskType.Site.Name">@taskType.Site.Name</MudSelectItem>
    }
  }
</MudSelect>
```

AddTask.razor.cs

```
IQueryable<TaskTypeModel>? taskTypes;

[Inject] public ApplicationDbContext dbContext { get; set; } = default;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
  taskTypes = dbContext.TaskTypes.Include(t => t.Site);
  foreach (var taskType in taskTypes)
  {
    // It print out all site without error
    Console.WriteLine(taskType.Site.Name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eager loading works just fine.

But because Value is a string type, I think what you need is the `@` in

```html
   <MudSelectItem Value="@taskType.Site.Name">
```

Comment: it still same. add @ in html attribute of visual code, break intellisense code.

Comment: I still think you need that `@`. Intellisense is easily confused and does not matter. Do restart VS, and do a Rebuild.